# Content behind the navbar

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an issue and i passed couple hours on finding what wrong.

The problem is the  is always behind the , like below

[image]

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-brook-5pxvl

Comment: Can you copy the code (it's better than an image ;) ). And if want to add  code part, you need to put this ` before and after you code, like \``<v-main>`\`. AND what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try your codesandbox. And it was just a problem from Vuetify version:

In package.json,
update from `"vuetify": "2.0.1"` to `"vuetify": "2.3.9"`

Comment: Thx for your response but i keep having same issue, im testing in a sandbox online: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-brook-5pxvl

Comment: Thx alot you saved my day :)